# spring graphql cursor base pagination with r2dbc

Tags: java, spring, graphql

When working with Spring Data R2DBC and GraphQL,implementing custom queries for pagination and sorting  when I execute it the api the SQL statement being run doesn't match your expectations

```
@Query("""
            SELECT p.*
            FROM product p
            WHERE date_trunc('month', to_timestamp(p.create_at)) = date_trunc('month', current_date)
            """
    )
    Mono<Window<Product>> getHotRecommendation(Long id, ScrollPosition position, Limit limit, Sort sort);  

@SchemaMapping
    public Mono<Window<Product>> getHotRecommendation(Product product, ScrollSubrange subrange, Optional<Sort> sort){
        ScrollPosition position=subrange.position().orElse(ScrollPosition.offset());
        Limit limit=Limit.of(subrange.count().orElse(10));

        Sort sort1 = sort.orElse(Sort.by("title").ascending());

        return productService.getHotRecommendation(product.getId(),position,limit,sort1);
    }
```

```
type Query {

    getHotRecommendation(first:Int,after:String,last:Int,before:String):ProductConnection!
}
the sql execute in the console
24-03-13T16:57:36.530+01:00 DEBUG 15980 --- [product] [actor-tcp-nio-1] o.s.r2dbc.core.DefaultDatabaseClient     : Executing SQL statement [SELECT product.* FROM product LIMIT 3]
```